# Calling Code-behind from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, onclick

On the click of a button, I call a JavaScript function. After getting the value, I need to perform some stuff from the value obtained in the code-behind. How should I call code-behind?

My aspx:

```
function openWindow(page) {
  var getval = window.showModalDialog(page);
  document.getElementById("<%= TxtInput.ClientID %>").value = getval; 
  //After this I need to perform stuff 'Upload(TxtInput.value)' into database from the code-behind
}
```

The button calling the function is set up in the following manner:

```
<button class="doActionButton" id="btnSelectImage" runat="server" onclick="openWindow('../rcwksheet/popups/uploader.htm')">Select Image</button>
```

My desired code behind (VB):

```
Public Sub btnSaveImage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelectImage.ServerClick
  Dim inputFile As String = Me.TxtInput.Value
  //do more stuff here
End Sub
```

So:

1. Is there a way to call code-behind from the JavaScript?
2. Can I somehow use the "onclick" property of a button to first go to a JavaScript and then to the code-behind?
3. Trigger a code-behind call "onchange" of the TxtInput.Value?

Comment: if you use web service like Jesper suggested, make sure you know how to secure your web service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264909/asp-net-is-my-web-service-secure-enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a way.

first, you can use javascript to submit the form after your return value is set in `TxtInput`.

```
function openWindow(page) {
  var getval = window.showModalDialog(page);
  document.getElementById("<%= TxtInput.ClientID %>").value = getval; 
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

then in your code behind, you can handle `TxtInput`'s value in page load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (this.Input.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            this.Input.Value += "blah";
        }
    }
}
```

note: you may need [Identifying control that caused postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319691/identifying-control-that-caused-postback)

Comment: If the page reloads again, and is a post back, can I still access the view state parameters?

Comment: if you mean access to view state on server side, the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using your solution. I marked all as answers, because theoretically they sound right, but I tried your thing.

Comment: you can only mark one as answer and looks like you marked Jesper's answer.

Comment: Changed. Please see if you can help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679769/image-uploading-and-retrieval-from-db2

Answer (score 0):

You can put the server side code into a web service, make a service reference in an asp:ScriptManager on your aspx page and then you can call/execute the web service from javascript by calling:

```
WebServiceClassName.MethodName(javascriptvariable, doSomethingOnSuccess)
```

Here is a link on doing that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can call the __doPostBack Event.

```
function openWindow(page) {
  var getval = window.showModalDialog(page);
  document.getElementById("<%= TxtInput.ClientID %>").value = getval; 
__doPostBack('btnSelectImage', getval);
}
```

And on the server side in your code behind, you can get the value:

In the PageLoad method:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "btnSelectImage")
{
    //get the argument passed
    string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    //fire event
    btnSaveImage_Click(this, new EventArgs());
}
```