# Image uploading and Retrieval from DB2

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, db2

H! I'm trying to upload an image in a DB2 database.
The image size is a JPG (6.76 kb - 6924 bytes).

The database table has a BLOB field of length 1048576.

My code to insert the image is as follows:

```
If fileup.PostedFile IsNot Nothing AndAlso fileup.PostedFile.FileName <> "" Then
   Dim imagesize As Byte() = New Byte(fileup.PostedFile.ContentLength - 1) {}
   Dim uploadedimage1 As HttpPostedFile = fileup.PostedFile

   uploadedimage1.InputStream.Read(imagesize, 0, CInt(fileup.PostedFile.ContentLength))

   Dim uploadedimage2 As New OleDbParameter("@Image", OleDbType.VarBinary, imagesize.Length)
   uploadedimage2.Value = imagesize

   Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO xxx_TBL(x, IMAGE)  VALUES (?, ?)"
   cmd.Parameters.Add(x)
   cmd.Parameters.Add(uploadedimage2)

   cmd.Connection = clsDatabase.Open_DB()
   Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   If result > 0 Then
      Return True
```

The image gets inserted into the Database.

The code to get the image from the Database, into a DataTable, which is then bound to a GridView to display on the webpage is as follows:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT x, IMAGE FROM xxx_TBL WHERE y = 1" 

cmd.Connection = clsDatabase.Open_DB()
Dim dReader As OleDbDataReader
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Comments", GetType(String)))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Picture", GetType(Bitmap)))

Do While (dReader.Read())
   Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

   dr("Comments") = dReader(0).ToString
   Dim imageobj = dReader(1)
       Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Dim bm As Bitmap
            Dim bytearray = DirectCast(imageobj, Byte())
            ms.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length)
            bm = New Bitmap(ms)
            dr("Picture") = bm
       End Using

    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Loop

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

x comes from the Database fine, and is displayed. However, I get no picture - just a small "missing picture (red cross on white) icon".

On checking the database, the length of the image in BLOB field is 8192. However, on copying it onto a 'TEST' File (no extension), the size was 13848 bytes. I'm guessing that could be because of the way DB2 reads/encodes the image binary, but I'm not sure.
Could someone please highlight the possible causes of error? Any suggestions on making this work or debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DB2 but since you are able to display `comments`, your `image` should be read properly. Let's assume your `image` data is also stored properly, your code will not display them in the browser because they need a little different care then `comments`. Each image needs to be an additional HTTP request to your server, so you'll have to create those `<img src=myImg.png>` tags in place of image holders.

In your `dt`, you don't need the actual image data, you just need the ID to the image because you'll need to use a `HttpHandler` to retrieve the image and then stream to browser.

first, you'll need a `<img>` tag in your GivdView1's image column.

then, during data binding, make sure to update it to `<img src="MyHttpHandler.ashx?id=1"/>`, of course, the ID value must be dynamic.

now, add a new file `Generic Handler` to your Visual Studio project and name it `MyHttpHandler.ashx` and code something like below:

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{    
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string sid = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
        int id = -1;
        if(int.TryParse(sid, out id) && id > 0){
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IMAGE FROM xxx_TBL WHERE ID=" + id.ToString() + ";";
            byte[] img = dr["IMAGE"];
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(img);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, after gridview renders the  html, the browser will make HTTP request for all those images and your `MyHttpHandler.ashx` will stream each image back for browser to display.

Comment: How can I make this work if the 'WHERE' clause of the SQL being used has more than one parameters.
I mean, for the HttpHandler, the SQL is like SELECT IMAGE FROM xxx_TBL WHERE vendor=x, report=y and SEQ=1.
The images are stored per vendor, per report, ordered by Sequence No. (SEQ). 
If I increment the SEQ no. in a loop, how can I be sure that the HttpHandler will return the images corresponding to the other data I am returning, like Picture Comments.

Comment: Is it possible to get the entire DataTable generated in the HttpHandler?

Comment: To give you and idea, following are the columns of the database table:
`Report Number(unique),
Vendor Number,
Image Comments,
Image,
Image SEQ No.`
There can be multiple images per Report, and so the SEQ no. gives the order in relation to the other column headers. It is of type INTEGER, Goes from 1-`n`, where `n` will be the number of rows in the database for the same Report Number (one row per image)

Comment: If your Report Number is unique, then you should create the image link with that number instead. `<img src="MyHttpHandler.ashx?rptid=1"/>`

Comment: I get that, but "SELECT IMAGE FROM IMAGE_TBL WHERE REPORTID=XXX" will return multiple images.
How can I tie these images with their corresponding comments and all, using the HTTPHandler?

Comment: If it returns multiples to you, that means your reportid is not a unique column. In your IMAGE_TBL, you need to have a unique column that can identify a single row. If you don't have it, you need multiple columns. In your query string, you can pass in multiple parameters. I saw you have Image SEQ No column, if that column is unique, then use that column.

Comment: Got it! That is what I was looking for. I'll have to pass a query string of Report and SEQ No.

Any example of how I may do that? From the aspx of GridView?

Comment: You can take a look at the link below. The idea is you need to find the `<img>` control in your `OnRowDataBind` event, and then convert it to `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage` class and then update its `src` attribute with your IDs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: Hi Ray! Another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855687/gridview-rowcommand-event-and-saving-text